# How to create an ambient declaration of a simple class

Tags: typescript

I have a simple external project (https://www.npmjs.com/package/undo-manager) and I want to create an ambient declaration (this is obviously wrong):

```
declare module "undo-manager" {
    interface UndoManager {
        setCallback(f:Function):void;
        undo():void;
        redo():void;
        hasUndo():boolean;
        hasRedo():boolean;
        add(cmd:Command):void;
    }
    interface Command {
        redo():any;
        undo():any;
    }
    interface UndoManagerFactory {
        new(): UndoManager;
    }
}
```

My question is how change the declaration, so that I can use the undo manager like this

```
var UndoManager = require('undo-manager');
// some more imports may be needed to get Command, but how?

undoManager = new UndoManager();

function addCmd(cmd: Command) {
    undoManager.add(cmd);
}
addCmd({
    redo: () => doSomething(),
    undo: () => undoSomething()
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition file should be

```
declare module "undo-manager" {
    module UndoManager {
        export interface Command {
            redo(): any;
            undo(): any;
        }
    }
    class UndoManager {
        setCallback(f: Function): void;
        undo(): void;
        redo(): void;
        hasUndo(): boolean;
        hasRedo(): boolean;
        add(cmd: UndoManager.Command): void;
    }

    export = UndoManager
}
```

Use it this way

```
import * as UndoManager from 'undo-manager'

const um = new UndoManager()

function addCmd(cmd: UndoManager.Command) {
    um.add(cmd)
}
```

Two comments:

1- There seems to be more public methods available in `UndoManager` than those listed in the definition file

2- Since we are at it, it would be nice that you contribute this definition file to [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) (or, even better, have the code author maintain it)

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. Because the javascript module `undo-manager` exports only the class `UndoManager`: in JavaScript you say `var UndoManager = require('undo-manager'); var undoManager = new UndoManager();`. In the Typescript module I could say `export = UndoManager;`, but heck, how to also export the `Command` interface????

Comment: OK. Completely reworked the answer above (and tested it :))

Comment: Great, now it works as expected. The trick seems to be to add a submodule with the same name as the exported class. I guess this would also work for properties on the class constructor function.

Comment: Yes. The `module`/`namespace` "trick" is actually pretty common to "augment" an existing definition. You can declare the constructor signature within a class.